# ASP.NET MVC turn-based game for anonymous user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am new to *ASP.NET MVC*.

I am trying to implement the game  [Rock-Paper-Scissors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors).

Implementation requirements:

1. Allow anonymous users play game (game must be private)
2. *SignalR* is prohibited to use

I read the similar question ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800263/how-to-connect-two-people-in-your-website)). I still have questions.

Where to create Session Player `Guid` (first time)?

A `Dictionary<player, game>` (mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800263/how-to-connect-two-people-in-your-website)) must be thread-safe?
Or I can just use it as static variable in `Global.asax.cs` ?

**UPDATE**:

Is it okay to store guest-player information in static dictionary?

Then how to remove expired session player informaion?

I think I need to implement `Session_Start` and `Session_End` methods in `Global.asax`.
And when session is expired delete player info. Is it good approach or not?

Comment: [Starting and Ending essions in ASP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524798%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). (_hint_ [`Session_Start(Object,EventArgs)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee255113%28v=bts.10%29.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

Session player GUID should be generated at stage when player hit PLAY button or whatever is should be a trigger for game beginning.

Instead of `Dictionary<player, game>` use ConcurrentDictionary. Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx). It should be static, not thread static. There you should store your game sessions.

If user refresh page or disconnected for a short period, you should allow him to restore his game. To do this you could store your game session guid in coockie or local storage (which will be send in header) and analise it on server side and decide to begin new game or continue old.

Very simple.

Comment: Thanks for reply! How to connect two users: one should waiting or create game?

Comment: First one create new game and allow new players to connect. Second player browse for opened games. If found joins to it. Game begin, opened status removed to prevent new players arrive.

Comment: when to remove elements from dictionary?

Comment: and why it is better to store as dictionary and not in database?

Comment: for small solutions - in memory, for large in db. Obviously removing elements from dictionary should occurs then game is over.